# Calculate raycasts(linecast) in the background to save performance Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi in my script I have to do a lot of raycast(linecast) queries. As a consequence the game hangs again and again. Finally all raycasts are calculated in the MainThread. But it does not have to be calculated immediately, it is enough if they are calculated slowly in the background.
does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: How many raycasts are you performing that you hang the game? Also have you considered splitting the raycasting out into a coroutine (and have that perform a couple of casts each frame)?

Comment: Also have you looked into the new job system yet? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand.html

Comment: i do more than 100 raycast i looked at the new job system is that also possibile with Linecasts? and is there maybe an easyer way?